# Запрет выполнения функции, пока функция не завершена

Tags: python, aiogram, pyrogram

**Python: aiogram + pyrogram**

Я пытаюсь реализовать управление несколькими аккаунтами Телеграм, с помощью Бота, то есть я могу дать задание определенному аккаунту, например: подписаться на список групп

Проблема:
Как мне узнать выполняется ли функция (подписаться на список групп) у этого аккаунта, если не выполняется, то функция начнет свою работу. Если же функция ещё не закончила свое выполнение, или пользователь не прервал ее, то запрещать повторно выполнять ее, так как она уже выполняется

Учитывая то, что у меня может быть X количество аккаунтов, они могут как добавляться, так и удаляться

При этом, другие аккаунты тоже могут попутно выполнять ту же самую операцию

Подскажите пожалуйста принцип реализации такого..?